# filter p:dataTable by date range with pagination

Tags: date, jsf, primefaces, pagination

I have made a PrimeFaces data table, which can be filtered (see below).  It works fine, but now I have attempted to create the ability to filter by start and end date, selecting dates via the calendar (it should find dates between those two dates; notice start date/end date and filter dates button at the top).  I need it to filter by start and end date just like it filters by everything else.

It is invoked via a custom method, but it doesn't return the correct values, and most importantly if I select another page on the paginator it defaults back to the unfiltered list.  Which is something of a disaster.  I'd like help to make it so that the user can filter by start/end date as part of the whole filtering system.  Right now start/end date fields are part of the header.

I thought maybe if the filter dates fields modify the list (bean property) used to pull the data for the table (tableFiltered), this will ensure the data pulled is always limited to the correct dates which have been filtered.  But it didn't work like that.  I don't understand.

[image]

Inside home.xhtml

```
<p:outputPanel id="tableContainer">
<p:remoteCommand name="filterByDate" action="#{homeController.FilterByDate()}" update="tableContainer" />
<p:dataTable var="hbel" id="hbelList" value="#{homeController.tableFiltered}" rows="10"
    paginator="true"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="10,100,1000"
    widgetVar="widgetTable"
    tableStyle="width:auto">

<f:facet name="header">
    <p:outputPanel>
    <p:calendar id="calStartDate" value="#{homeController.startDate}" maxdate="#{homeController.endDate}" navigator="true" pattern="dd-MMM-yy" placeholder=" start date">
        <p:ajax process="calStartDate" partialSubmit="true" event="change"/> 
    </p:calendar>

    <p:calendar id="calEndDate" value="#{homeController.endDate}" maxdate="#{homeController.endDate}" navigator="true" pattern="dd-MMM-yy" placeholder=" end date">
        <p:ajax process="calEndDate" partialSubmit="true" event="change"/> 
    </p:calendar>

    <p:commandButton id="btnFilter" value="Filter Dates" ajax="true">
        <p:ajax oncomplete="filterByDate()" />
    </p:commandButton>

    </p:outputPanel>
</f:facet>

    <p:column filterStyle="width: 48px;" filterBy="#{hbel.batchId}" headerText="BatchID" filterMatchMode="exact">
        <h:outputText value="#{hbel.batchId}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column filterStyle="width: 48px;" filterBy="#{hbel.recordId}" headerText="RecordID" filterMatchMode="exact">
        <h:outputText value="#{hbel.recordId}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column filterBy="#{hbel.unitName}" headerText="UnitName" filterMatchMode="in">
        <f:facet name="filter">
            <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Unit" onchange="PF('widgetTable').filter()" panelStyle="width:125px" scrollHeight="150">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Location" itemValue="LOCATION"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Unit" itemValue="UNIT" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Customer" itemValue="DIRECT_CUSTOMER" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Occupancy" itemValue="OCCUPANCY" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Bank Account" itemValue="BANK_ACCOUNT" />
            </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{hbel.unitName}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column filterBy="#{hbel.logDate}" headerText="LogDate" filterMatchMode="exact">
        <h:outputText value="#{hbel.logDate}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column filterBy="#{hbel.logFlag}" headerText="LogFlag" filterMatchMode="in">
        <f:facet name="filter">
            <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Flag" onchange="PF('widgetTable').filter()" panelStyle="width:125px" scrollHeight="150">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Business" itemValue="B"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Reconciliation" itemValue="R" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Technical" itemValue="T" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Warning" itemValue="W" />
             </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{hbel.logFlag}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column filterBy="#{hbel.logFields}" headerText="LogFields" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{hbel.logFields}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column filterBy="#{hbel.logReason}" headerText="LogReason" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{hbel.logReason}" />
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Inside homeController.java bean (request scoped)

```
    // custom filtering
    public void FilterByDate()
    {
        if (startDate != null &&
            endDate != null)
        {
            // new dates (add start and end date to range)
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            c.setTime(startDate); 
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
            Date startDateMod = c.getTime();
            c.setTime(endDate); 
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            Date endDateMod = c.getTime();

            // reset table first
            tableFiltered.clear();
            // add legal items from tableFull
            for (HubToBauExceptionLog hbel : tableFull)
            {
                if (hbel != null &&
                    hbel.getLogDate().after(startDateMod) && 
                    hbel.getLogDate().before(endDateMod))
                {
                    tableFiltered.add(hbel);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Primefaces docs:

> **Filtering**
>
> Ajax based filtering is enabled by setting filterBy at
> column level and providing a list to keep the filtered sublist. It is
> suggested to use a scope longer than request like viewscope to keep
> the filteredValue so that filtered list is still accessible after
> filtering.

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{carBean.cars}"
             filteredValue="#{carBean.filteredCars}">
    <p:column filterBy="#{car.model}" headerText="Model">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
    </p:column>
    ...more columns
</p:dataTable>
```

So try to add to your dataTable a list for the filteredValue, keep the tableFull as value and in FilterByDate method populate the filtered list.

```
<p:dataTable var="hbel" id="hbelList" 
    value="#{homeController.tableFull}" rows="10"
    filteredValue="#{homeController.tableFiltered}"
    paginator="true"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="10,100,1000"
    widgetVar="widgetTable"
    tableStyle="width:auto">
```

Comment: Thank you!  I added "filteredValue" to the dataTable parameters, and also changed homeController's scope to application, and it works now!